# Encountered two children with the same key,

Tags: material-ui, material-table

I'm working on material table in react and when I try to delete or updated my row datas then I'm monitoring this error all of times.

Update Error: react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `row-cc5026f5-6a53-4f91-850d-3127467a8615`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Delete Error: Nothing happening when I Try to delete.

What's wrong with my codes?

here is Table.js

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from '@material-table/core';
import axios from 'axios';
import { emplist as RoomInfo } from './data/emplist';

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(RoomInfo);

    const columns = [
        {
            title: 'ID',
            field: 'id',
        },
        {
            title: 'Floor Name',
            field: 'FloorName',
        },
        {
            title: 'Building Name',
            field: 'BuildingName',
        },
        {
            title: 'Room Code',
            field: 'RoomCode',
        },
        {
            title: 'Room Name',
            field: 'RoomName',
        },
        {
            title: 'Room Area',
            field: 'RoomArea',
        },
        {
            title: 'Room Perimeter',
            field: 'RoomPerimeter',
        },
        {
            title: 'Room Height',
            field: 'RoomHeight',
        },
    ];
    return (
        <MaterialTable
            title="Editable Preview"
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            editable={{
                onRowAdd: (newRow) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const updatedRows = [
                            ...data,
                            { id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), ...newRow },
                        ];
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            setData(updatedRows);
                            resolve();
                        }, 2000);
                    }),
                onRowDelete: (selectedRow) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const index = selectedRow.tableData.id;
                        const updatedRows = [...data];
                        updatedRows.splice(index, 1);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            setData(updatedRows);
                            resolve();
                        }, 1000);
                    }),
                 onRowUpdate: (selectedRow, oldRow) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const index = oldRow.tableData.id;
                        const updatedRow = [...data];
                        updatedRows[index] = updatedRow;
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            setData(updatedRows);
                            resolve();
                        }, 1000);
                    }),
    
            }}
            options={{
                actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                addRowPosition: 'first',
            }}
        />
    );
}

export default App;
```

Hi everyone, I'm working on material table in react and when I try to delete or updated my row datas then I'm monitoring this error all of times.

Update Error: react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `row-cc5026f5-6a53-4f91-850d-3127467a8615`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Delete Error: Nothing happening when I Try to delete.

What's wrong with my codes?

Comment: Make sure that the data source has all its ids unique, maybe there's two duplicate ids in the data set

Comment: I updated all row Id and now when I click to save or delete button nothing happening. I can only new data into table and I can't edit or delete that is a last added in the table.